# ctrl + insert on a mac while connected using vim on a virtual machine running windows

Tags: windows, macos, vim, clipboard

I am using a macbook air but in order to access my company's servers I have to use a virtual desktop that runs windows. I'm using putty/vim and can't figure out how to paste something as the is no "insert" key on the mac. Does anyone no a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click in the putty window to paste, (two finger click on touchpad).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Explanation

Vim (vi too, to be honest) has 26 built-in private buffers (a-z). vim has also buffers for the clipboard.

To Put (insert) from buffer `m`, you would do `"mp` which reads as "with  buffer m do the put thing".

To put from Clipboard, you have to find the right buffer in your setup.

1. Try opening a temp-file with no meaning and no risk. Then copy something in your Windows or your mac.
2. Go into the vim- putty with the simple file.
3. type `"*p` , I mean type first `<Doublequote>` then `<Star>` then ```
4. Is your paste happening? Be happy
5. if not: try `"+p` for "with buffer `+` do `p`ut

One of them should work.

In short:

Use one of the Buffers '+' or '*', so:

```
"*p  
"+p
```

If you want to yank into general buffer, use one of

```
"*y
"+y
```

and look, which one works.

Happy vim-ing!

You can also find a key on Mac to map this command to. `:he :map`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I must be dense because I still don't understand what I should do

Comment: `%s/buffer/register/g`